# Open Bounty (get reputation back)

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, ethics

I noticed this behavior on SO, this is the case:

- A user opens a bounty for a question (let's say 300 points)
- This questions tends to be more difficult compared to a regular question
- The user get a good quality answers
- The user answers it's own question based on the answer he got from other people

According to this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97001/getting-bounty-offer-back)

> half amount of bounty will be awarded to the answer that is given
>   after bounty is placed and has highest votes

so is there could be the case to get more votes on it's own answer and get the points back?
to me that could considered as some way of cheating, is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: From the linked faq: *The answer must not have been written by the bounty starter*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, even if you answer your own question and it gets the most votes after you place a bounty, no part of it will be returned to you.

[Lost reputation after answering my own question with bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18841/lost-reputation-after-answering-my-own-question-with-bounty)